# В чем разница между исходным кодом, пакетом и репозиторием

Tags: linux, установка, пакет

Занимаюсь изучением Linux.
На данный момент прохожу тему "Как устанавливается ПО в Linux".
Не могу понять в чем разница установки с помощью исходного кода, из пакета или репозитория. Пробовал гуглить много инфы но я все равно не могу понять !

Прошу Вас помочь разобраться в этом непростом вопросе, большая просьба по возможности объясните простым языком если можно с примерами, скринами как выглядит и в чем различия каждого способа установки ПО.

P.S. Насколько я понял установка из исходного кода это когда ты самостоятельно устанавливаешь каждый файл программы отдельно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131194/discussion-on-question-by-karaban--------).

Answer (score 0):

> в чем разница установки с помощью исходного кода, из пакета или
> репозитория.

1. Из исходного кода:

   - Скачиваете архив исходного кода приложения (как правило - из github)
   - Распаковываете скачанный архив
   - *make*
   - *sudo make install*
2. Из пакета:

   - Скачиваете файл пакета приложения (например) <имя пакета>.rpm
   - *sudo rpm -i <имя пакета>.rpm*
3. Из репозитария:

   - *sudo dnf install <имя приложения>*

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что в первом случаее Вы используете имя **архива**, во втором - имя **пакета**, а в третьем - имя **приложения**